# Windows PC's Intermittant Network faults

Tags: networking, connection

im running into some issues with our client PC's (windows xp sp3 systems).

this morning we ran into some problems with PC's not connecting to internal / external systems intermittantly. this would manifest as a problem connecting to any service, email, web, backoffice database systems etc.

given a random amount of time be it a few minutes etc the problem would disapear and the pc would carry on as normal, some systems however have not been able to connect to certain sytems since the problem initally happened.

im hoping for some suggestions / network diag advice really to help me locate the cause of this problem.

all the clients are windows xp, connecting to a domain controller that is windows 2003 std this server also acts as a DNS server for us. we also have websense 7.0.1 installed on it to filter traffic.

Comment: The domain controller, is it acting as a DHCP server? If so are all your clients properly receiving IP addresses and DNS? When service would go out did all connections go down or was it random? IE: could you ping a local printer but not 4.2.2.2 or vice versa.

Comment: Hi, the domain controller is not providing DHCP addresses our private network is setup using static addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear this question up and answer it, the problem came down to a firmware upgrade on a firewall. this had been done in the evening with little traffic on our network so no problems had been seen.

However the minute the whole network was loaded up with traffic it manifested. After reverting the firewall firmware the problem stopped, however we have also been in communication with the firewall company for a few months since and have had no resolution to this problem.

Our eventual resolution was to move away from there firewall and bring in some more standardised equipment (cisco). network is now running fine and very quick.